# xlPart vs xlWhole

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering how Excel VBA prioritizes searches when using xlPart vs. xlWhole.

The first row in my worksheet contains header text for many columns.  Depending on who generates this report and what settings they use, the header text can change - both locations and content.  For that reason, I'm using the .Find method with "Lookat:=xlPart" to search for substrings that I know will always be present.

The problem I'm running into is that I want to find the first (left-most) column containing the text "Job ID".  Column A contains the exact text "Job ID", and column Z contains the text "Master Job ID".  But this line of code always returns column Z instead of column A which is the left-most column for which that criteria should find a match:

```
Set FoundRange = Range(SearchRange).Find(What:="Job ID", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

If I change it to "Lookat:=xlWhole", it returns column A, as it should.  But why doesn't it find a match in column A using "Lookat:=xlPart"?

If I change the contents of cell Z1 so there is no substring match to "Job ID", then .Find will correctly return column A regardless of whether I use xlPart or xlWhole.  It seems to me that it should always return column A in this case.

Is there some subtlety that I'm missing?

Comment: You might need to specify the `After` parameter too.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method includes an optional parameter `After`.  This specifies where the search starts, literally at the cell *after* the specified cell.  When not specified it defaults to the first cell in the search range.

In your example, searching a single row (row 1?) without specifying After, the search starts at `B1`.  That's why it finds `Z1` first.

To start at the first cell, specify After as the last cell in the search range

```
After:=SearchRange.Cells(SearchRange.Cells.Count)
```

Comment: Ah, now I understand - thank for the tip.  Although it does seem strange that the .Find method doesn't start with the fiest element in the specified range.  That's very unintuitive.

Comment: Well, it's actually it's quite useful when doing multiple searches.  You just supply the last found cell as After, it'll then find the next one